# I tried unwrapping my model and this is what I got, how can I fix this?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLzQcZtW7ENSTyTjvmsv69HzLETb8dDS/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Apparently, it only works well when I try to unwrap the objects individually, I've checked the marked seams and nothing seems to be wrong.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Other people I've asked to check my file didn't encounter any errors like I did, so it's it's still a surprise why I'm the only one facing it. What Blender version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me in case I have done something wrong but your model seem to be perfectly fine in the UV editor, everything is neatly unwrapped
[image]

I can't seem to find the error here so I'll say have you tried recalculating your normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> select the calculate from inside option and retry unwrapping?

If that fails too then try unwrapping via the Smart UV Project option.

Comment: I agree. Would like to see an image of the "problem"!